# Adding a command to the ptokax GUI so as to give Profile Permissions

Tags: lua, ptokax

As there are the commands like tempban, permban, etc which can be given permissions for profiles using the ptokax GUI under the profile manager.

I have made a script and i want to add my command to the GUI.
How can i do this?

Comment: Can you explain your question a little more?

Comment: if u use ptokax u can see under the profile manager window u can give permissions to profiles for commands like ban,gag,etc.i wanted to add my command to this list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can not allow certain profiles to use commands which **you have written or created**. Instead, you'd have to handle this from your own scripts. For example, let's say you have profile levels from `0` (Master) to `6` (regular user) along with the profile `-1` for unregistered users.

If you want your command to be accessible by only certain profiles, create a hash table:

```
tAllowedProfiles = {
    [-1] = false,
    [0] = true,
    [1] = false,
    [2] = false,
    [3] = true,
    [4] = true,
    [5] = true,
    [6] = false
}
```

and then, in your `ChatArrival` or `ToArrival` functions, you can match the user's profile against the has table created above:

```
function ChatArrival( tUser, sMessage )
    if not tAllowedProfiles[tUser.iProfile] then return false end
    -- deal with the command/message otherwise
end
```

This is true for the GUI client for Windows as well. You can look over a few of [my own scripts for reference](https://github.com/hjpotter92/ptokax-scripts).

Comment: @mental You're welcome! You can select it as an answer if it helped and the question won't appear under unsolved questions list :)